# Are defaulted functions inline functions in C++20?

Tags: c++, class, struct, language-lawyer, c++20

In this code:

```
struct tmp
{
    int va = 0;
    tmp() = default;
    bool operator==(const tmp& rhv) const = default; //(in c++20)
};
```

Are the constructor `tmp()` and `operator==` inline functions, even though I didn't add the "inline" keyword in front of them?

If the answer is yes, what will happen if add a "inline" in front of them?

And can I force them to be regular functions? (Although I don't know which object file can store them.)

Comment: See [Are the default constructor and destructor ever inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273958/are-the-default-constructor-and-destructor-ever-inline) and [Why are the default constructor and destructor of a class inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926619/why-are-the-default-constructor-and-destructor-of-a-class-inline)

Comment: @JasonLiam The question is about explicitly declared functions defined with `= default`, both your duplicates are about implicitly declared functions.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Note that both "explicitly defaulted function" as well as "implicitly declared functions" are collectively called **defaulted functions** and implementation shall provide implicit definitions for them. I've reopened the question anyways.

Comment: What do you hope to gain from making them *not* `inline`?

Comment: What do you mean by `inline`?  I'd hazard a guess that doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the constructor tmp() and operator== inline functions, even though I didn't add the "inline" keyword in front of them?

Yes, this can be seen from [dcl.fct.def.def.default#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.def.default#3) which states:

> An explicitly-defaulted function that is not defined as deleted may be declared constexpr or consteval only if it is constexpr-compatible ([special], [class.compare.default]).
> **A function explicitly defaulted on its first declaration is implicitly inline** ([dcl.inline]), and is implicitly constexpr ([dcl.constexpr]) if it is constexpr-compatible.

(emphasis mine)

And since both `tmp::tmp()` as well as `bool tmp::operator==(const tmp&) const` are **explicitly defaulted** on their respective first declaration, both of them are **implicitly inline**.

---

> If the answer is yes, what will happen if add a "inline" in front of them?

As both are already implicitly inline, the effect of explicitly adding `inline` infront of them will be the same as not adding `inline` explicitly.

---

> And can I force them to be regular functions?

You can avoid them being *implicitly inline* by not explicitly defaulting the member functions in their first declarations so that the above quoted rule does not apply. For example,

```
struct tmp
{
    int va = 0;
    tmp(); //don't default here in the first declaration
    
};
tmp::tmp() = default;
int main()
{
    tmp t; //the default ctor is not "implicitly inline"
}
```

Comment: Sorry wrong question,I corrected it(can I force them...),and can I force them to be regular functions?

Comment: @LiiiiEW Explicitly adding `inline` infront of them won't have any extra effect as they are already "implicitly inline".

Comment: I means can I force them to regular function(NOT inline) in C++20.

Comment: @LiiiiEW You can do this by avoiding explicitly defaulting the member functions in their first declarations so that the above quoted rule from the standard does not apply.  See my updated answer where i gave a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zoro3Mj4T).

Comment: @LiiiiEW You can define them in a way that makes them not `inline` functions as defined by the standard, but there is no standards-based way to prevent the compiler from inlining them in any case. The as-if rule allows the compiler to emit inlined machine code even for calls to non-`inline` functions.